# O que exatamente é o HDFS

Tags: sistema-de-arquivos, big-data, hadoop

Bom dia,
Estou estudando sobre Hadoop e uma dúvida me surgiu, por exemplo se fala muito do HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System), que seria o armazenador de arquivos do Hadoop, minha dúvida é a seguinte, onde exatamente é ou onde fica esse HDFS? É um lugar especifico? Ou eu posso criar criar pastas em qualquer lugar do meu computador, colocar arquivos e considerar como sendo um HDFS.

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html (en Ingles) e aqui (em portugues) https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/wa-introhdfs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pra resumir a longa história, ele é como se fosse um sistema de arquivos  assim como você tem na sua maquina para windows (FAT32) ou linux (ext2, ext3, ReiserFS, XFS, JFS, UFS) , só que além desse modelo ter suporte a sistemas distribuídos ele também é tolerante a falhas. Foi o HDFS que tornou o hadoop  possível,  como se trata de um modelo distribuído ele roda o mesmo Map e Reduce em cada Node onde existe uma cópia do arquivo , em casa de um Node falhar , o trabalho estará garantido por que o Hadoop poderá encontrar o mesmo arquivo em outro Node.

Comment: Gilberto, me desculpa mas ainda ta um pouco confuso pra mim, a explicação ficou boa, porem ainda não consegui assimilar muito bem, por exemplo eu tenho um cluster de máquinas, e vamos supor que na maquina x eu tenha uma pasta em documentos e quero que o hdfs pegue os arquivos de lá, na outra máquina y a minha pasta fica em  disco local e eu quero que hdfs pegue de la, essa é a duvida rs eu posso mandar ele pegar de qualquer pasta? Ou ele tem uma pasta especifica que ele cria quando instalado e os arquivos tem que ficar la

Comment: Sim , basicamente, voce 'envia' arquivos para o HDFS (Node master) e aguarde ele fazer o resto, no caso a clusterização para os outros nodes. o seguinte command permite que vc envie arquivos da sua maquina local para o HDFS fs put --from source_path_and_file --to dest_path_and_file para rodar esse commando , voce precisa de uma instalação completa do hadoop , preferencialmente no linux .